# Generation/Synthesis of Data with CNNs

Tags: convolution, gan, generative-models

Is it possible to use a trained CNN to generate data? After training on data of X and corresponding Ys, given a new Y to generate X? 
Or do I have to use GANs or RNNs? I'm still pretty new to the subject so I would be happy to have some leads, if I have to go in this direction.

Currently I am learning tensorflow  and trying to implement the "Convolutional Sequence to Sequence Learning" paper

Clarification: I want to use a CNN to generate sequences of text. I have a reallyb big database of descriptions and also one of 1000 classes, and wanted to try it out with CNNs (since im coming from image classification)

Comment: The deep learning book has a whole section on [generative models](http://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/generative_models.html). You are advised to read on from here. GANs are a popular choice lately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if you want to generate data in X, or X, Y pairs, then you should start by training a generative model - as opposed to a discriminative model, which is what most NN classifiers are. There are many types of generative model.

[Variational Autoencoders](http://kvfrans.com/variational-autoencoders-explained/) (VAE)and [Generative Adversarial Networks](http://blog.aylien.com/introduction-generative-adversarial-networks-code-tensorflow/) (GAN) have been demonstrated recently with interesting results on images - although both take a lot of training data and time, and are limited to relatively small image dimensions (e.g. 128x128). There are many sub-types of these two designs, including a [combined VAEGAN](https://github.com/anitan0925/vaegan) which attempts to combine strengths of both.

With a trained CNN, you *can* generate data - sort of. What you can do is start with some arbitrary value of X and Y, then use back propagation to calculate gradients of a cost function. But instead of using the gradients to update weights, you back propagate all the way to the input, and use the gradients at the input to alter X, repeating the process multiple times.

This is essentially how Deep Dream and Style Transfer work (although in general these don't use a Y value, but selected activation values within layers). There is a major caveat to this approach - your generated X will not be sampled evenly from any distribution of X that the network has been trained with. Instead you will generate a "super stimulus" X for the given Y.

You mention RNNs. One way these can be used to generate X is by [sampling from their output and feeding this back into the input](http://karpathy.github.io/2015/05/21/rnn-effectiveness/). For text sequences this tends to generate grammatically correct nonsense. I am not sure if this would be considered a strictly generative model, since it is not clear to me whether the input X is being sampled evenly. It is likely that you could use the approach to generate images too, although you would have to take care defining what the sequence is (just a sequence of pixels line-by-line will probably not produce any recognisable image).

Comment: Thank zou for this elaborate answer. I'm mainly focusing on generating text, but coming from Image classification, I wanted to explore the possibilities of NLP with CNNs.

I will look into GAN/VAE and also how to (if possible) aplly Deep Dream or similiar for this purpose.